# addEventListener из одного метода не видит другой метод этого же класса

Tags: javascript, события

Всем привет! Не могу понять, почему addEventListener из одного метода класса не видит другой метод этого же класса. Получаю ошибку Uncaught TypeError: this.movePath is not a function. Из других методов метод movePath(path) доступен. Код такой

```html
movePath(path) {
        console.log(path)
    }
    
addEventListeners() {
        const command = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.file'))
        command.forEach(function(command) {
            command.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e) {
                this.movePath(e.target.dataset.name);
            }, false)
        })
    }
```

Заранее спасибо!
UPD.
`self.movePath(e.target.dataset.name);`
тоже не работает

Comment: а это self из воздуха у вас, надо полагать, взялось?

Answer (score 0):

Это зависит от того, как вы используете этот класс. Поэтому вы должны использовать

```
 static movePath(){
 console.log('Some text')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот таким образом решается проблема потери контекста.

```
addEventListeners() {
        let that = this;// тут
        const command = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.file'))
        command.forEach(function(command) {
            command.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e) {
                that.movePath(e.target.dataset.name);
            })
        })
    }
```

Вроде как есть еще варианты решения с call или aply но я решил воспользоваться этим способом